# Nested exhaustMap and concatMap for Firebase Authentication RxJs

Tags: angular, firebase, rxjs, firebase-authentication, observable

I'm trying to implement Firebase Authentication and sending received user's data to the server for creating account in my app.

Here is the code:

```
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    fromEvent(this.LoginWithGoogle.nativeElement, 'click')
      .pipe(
         exhaustMap(() =>
           from(this.afAuth.signInWithPopup(provider)).pipe(
              map((data) => data.user),
              concatMap((user) =>
                this.authService.loginWithGoogle({
                   email: user.email,
                   username: user.displayName,
                })
              )
           )
         )
       )
       .subscribe((res) => {
           console.log(res);
       });
  }
```

It works well. But is it right to use nested RxJs operators like this? And there is any alternative solution for this case?

Answer (score 2):

I think this would work:

```js
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
  
  fromEvent(this.LoginWithGoogle.nativeElement, 'click')
    .pipe(
        exhaustMap(() => from(this.afAuth.signInWithPopup(provider))),
        map((data) => data.user),
        concatMap((user) => this.authService.loginWithGoogle({ 
            email: user.email,
            username: user.displayName,
          })
        )
      )
      .subscribe((res) => {
          console.log(res);
      });
}
```

When you're using operators like `switchMap`, `exhaustMap`, `mergeMap`, `concatMap`, which handle **inner observables** automatically, you can simply imagine that instead of manually subscribing to that the callback returns, you let that job do be done by the operator. In addition to this, the value emitted by the **inner observable** is passed along to the outer observable(most of the times - the main stream). That's why I was able to use `map` on the save level as `exhaustMap`.

#### Edit

If you also want to handle errors in inner observables, you can use something like this:

```js
exhaustMap(() => from(...).pipe(catchError(() => EMPTY)))
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but I do not know how to handle with 2 errors that come from inner observables

Comment: @Daniel What do you mean by `2 errors` ? Does it not work with `catchError` ?

Comment: Yes, it does. However, when `an error` was thrown from `exhaustMap`, the stream seem collapse and it can not receive any value from click event. I don't know how to handle with this problem

Comment: @Daniel does this work? : `exhaustMap(() => from(...).pipe(catchError(() => EMPTY)))`

Comment: Thanks for your help. It works as expected

Comment: @Daniel I'm glad it helped! I've updated the answer.